# Accessing cart.order_items.length gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

That's what's says compiler when I run my Django and ReactJs ecommerce app. What do I need to do with this?

Error place is shown as in `cart.js`

```
>    53 |   text={`${cart !== null ? cart.order_items.length : 0}`} 
> ^  54 |   pointing
```

error place is shown as in `Layout.js`

```
>    33 |     dispatch(cartSuccess(res.data));
> ^  34 |   })
```

In `action/cart.js`

```
export const fetchCart = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(cartStart());
    authAxios
      .get(orderSummaryURL)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(cartSuccess(res.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(cartFail(err));
      });
  };
};
```

In `Layout.js`

```
<Menu.Menu inverted position="right">
  <Dropdown
    icon="filter"
    loading={loading}
    text={`${cart !== null ? cart.order_items.length : 0}`}
    pointing
    className="link item"
  >
    <Dropdown.Menu>
      <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Divider />
      <Dropdown.Header>Header Item</Dropdown.Header>
      <Dropdown.Item>
        <i className="dropdown icon" />
        <span className="text">Submenu</span>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
</Menu.Menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null value check you are applying is on the `cart` object and not the property `order_items`. So in case if the value of `cart.order_items` is `undefined` or `null` this error occurs. In order to make sure you don't read length of undefined or null value you need to apply the check on the `order_items` property as well.

Replacing line 53 with this will solve your problem:

```
text={`${cart ? (cart.order_items ? cart.order_items.length : 0) : 0}`}
```

To understand in more depth how this condition works see the snippet below:

```js
const cart0 = null
const cart1 = undefined
const cart2 = {}
const cart3 = { order_items: null }
const cart4 = { order_items: [] }
const cart5 = { order_items: ["Apple", "Banana", "Pineapple"] }

function cartLength(detail, cart) {
 console.log(
  detail,
  cart
   ? cart.order_items
    ? cart.order_items.length
    : "cart.order_items is undefined or null"
   : "Cart undefined or null"
 )
}

cartLength("Cart 0: ", cart0)
cartLength("Cart 1: ", cart1)
cartLength("Cart 2: ", cart2)
cartLength("Cart 3: ", cart3)
cartLength("Cart 4: ", cart4)
cartLength("Cart 5: ", cart5)
```